# Dynamic defined message in gRPC GO

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am a new user of gRPC in Go.

I have completed my code about client streaming API. And now I have a question.

With my knowledge, we must define message struct in proto file, then the protoc based on this defined message struct to generate code. In my case, protoc generate Go code. But this process limit the client or the server reuses API. For example, with client-streaming API, firstly, the client use this API to send temperature data to server. Then the client must re-defind message struct if the client want to send GPS coordinates  to server, because the contruct of temperature is different from the contruct of GPS coordinates. But for the same purpose is send data to server.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package calculator;
option go_package="calculatorpb";
message TemperatureRequest{
     float num =1;
}
message TemperatureResponse{
     float result =1;
}
message CoordinatesRequest{
     float long =1;
     float lat =1;
}
message CoordinatesResponse{
     float result =1;
}
service  CalculatorService{
   rpc Temperature(stream AverageRequest) returns (AverageResponse){} //client streaming for temperature    
   rpc Coordinates(stream CoordinatesRequest) returns (CoordinatesResponse){} //client streaming  for  Coordinates
}
```

It seem be inconvenient.

So, how the client can use dynamic message struct with gRPC in go?

If yes, please give me an example of the client-streaming API.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic message struct? Can server share proto file to client in some means?

Comment: There's nothing dynamic in this. your methods are taking and returning predefined data type.

Comment: @sonus21 Yes. I don't know how to make it become dynamic. I mean, How can I use one function for client streaming any message struct to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) message type:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message Example {
    string id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any message = 2;
}
```

With `Any`, you can use any user-defined proto message, also you need to share the new proto message with the client using some common repo or registry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i understood your question properly, but i'll assume I have. Protobuf is a way to define communication protocol between two services, without limiting the underlying technology of those servers.

The code generated by `protoc` has only the purpose of communicating between services. If you want to have extra methods and stub code over them, you need wrapper structs on both ends. Because this is the idiomatic way to use protobuf

eg.

```
type MyStruct{

pb.Mystruct

}

func (m MyStruct) CalculateWeather() (int,error){

...

}
```

---

Normally, you should define different structs for each case. I am not sure what you want, but you could simply marshal your objects and send bytes over, and unmarshal back

Comment: I have edited my question for clearly. I mean, How can I use one function for client streaming any message struct to server. Please help me.

Comment: edited, but i really do not understand what you want to achieve

Comment: I mean "how can I make client streaming API with any message struct"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're asking for is:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package calculator;
option go_package="calculatorpb";

// message TemperatureRequest, TemperatureResponse, CoordinatesRequest, CoordinatesResponse defined as in your example

message DataRequest {
  TemperatureRequest temperature_request = 1;
  CoordinatesRequest coordinates_request = 2;
}
message DataResponse {
  TemperatureResponse temperature_response = 1;
  CoordinatesResponse coordinates_response = 2;
}

service  CalculatorService{
   rpc Data(stream DataRequest) returns (DataResponse){} //client streaming for data
}
```

Remember that `DataRequest` and `DataResponse` are extensible, so you can add fields to them in the future, if desired.

Comment: Thank you Mr Doug Fawley, I know we can extensible message struct, but when we extend, we must edit code, use protoc to generate code again, redeploy client service. 
My aim is find the way to skip these steps. For example, client can define his message struct in json file then protoc read this file and stream message. 
In my opinion, client only streaming data so it doesn't care  message struct.

Comment: I have an idea. Can I define message struct as byte[]. Then when client have data (string, json, struct, or anythings), first it converts theat data to byte[] and streaming to server. The server receive []byte stream con re-converts.  Is this idea reasonable?

Comment: If you want to do this, better than a `bytes` field would be to use an `Any`: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any